# Handle network response and parse it

Tags: java, android, api

First I have method called in `LoginActivity` to call my login API. This is my Listener that reads user input and then passes it to a method to call the API:

```
OnClickListener onSigninClick = new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String Pass = password.getText().toString();
            String userName = username.getText().toString();
            if (userName.equals("") || Pass.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.enterempty),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                progressD.show();
                userdata user = new userdata();
                user.password = Pass;
                user.username = userName;
                // check network connectivity 
                if (api.isNetworkConnected()) {
                    // api method 
                    get_user_data(user);
                } else {
                  // if there not internet connection 
                  // which better toast or alert dialog 
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.nointernet),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


        }
    };




  // method fot api 
    private void get_user_data(userdata user) {
           // my JSON parser class
            final JsonParsing jsonParser = new JsonParsing();
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(AppConstants.TAG_username, user.username);
            params.put(AppConstants.TAG_userpassword, user.password);

            String URL = AppConstants.GeneralURL + AppConstants.ACTION + AppConstants.LOGIN;

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                String res = response.getString("result");

                                if (res.equals("false")) {
                                    String error = (String) response.get("message");
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else if (res.equals("true")) {
                                    userdata user=  jsonParser.getUserDataObject((JSONObject) response.get("message"));
    // navigate to main view 
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // handle error
                }
            });

            MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getResquestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }
```

My response JSON has two cases:

`{"result" : "false" ,"message":"invalid user"}` // in fail case

In success credential, user data returned:

```
{"result" : "true" ,"message":{"user_id" : "60" , .......} }
```

My parser class:

```
public class JsonParsing {
    public userdata getUserDataObject(JSONObject jsonobject) {
        userdata user = new userdata();
        try {
            if (jsonobject.has("user_id")) {
                user.userid = jsonobject.getString("user_id");
            }
            if (jsonobject.has("user_mail")) {
                user.email = jsonobject.getString("user_mail");
            }

            if (jsonobject.has("user_age")) {
                user.age = jsonobject.getString("user_age");
            }
            if (jsonobject.has("user_name")) {
                user.username = jsonobject.getString("user_name");
            }
            if (jsonobject.has("user_password")) {
                user.password = jsonobject.getString("user_password");
            }
            if (jsonobject.has("user_photo")) {
                user.userimageURL = jsonobject.getString("user_photo");
            }
            if (jsonobject.has("posts")) {
                JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                    user.questionItems.add(getQuestionData(array
                            .getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Could any one review my code? I want to design the class to handle the network response in two case, and parse it if successful.  Are there any other tips on reducing my code?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other tips on reducing my code?

By reducing, not sure if you meant shortening.
If yes, then you can reduce the duplication in the parser, using a helper method like this:

```
private String getString(JSONObject jsonobject, String name) {
    return jsonobject.has(name) ? jsonobject.getString(name) : null;
}
```

#### Exception handling

Try to limit the scope of try-catch blocks as much as possible, to include only the sensitive part of the code where an exception might happen.
I don't have a compiler with me now but it seems to me that you could reduce the scope at some places.

#### Checking for empty strings

Instead of `.equals("")`, use the more idiomatic `isEmpty()`.

#### Naming

The convention for method names is `camelCase`, don't use `snake_case`.

#### Pointless comments

Some of the comments are pointless, noise, for example:

> ```
>             // check network connectivity 
>             if (api.isNetworkConnected()) {
> ```

I suggest to remove such comments.